# Applying values in a class from a generic method

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a simple Gun class and i want to have attachable components to it. So i use a generic type for my Attatch method since their are different component types.

My problem is i don't know how to assign the value to the object in the method - i think i might have misunderstood the logic of generics. This is my code:

```
public class Gun : Weapon
{

    public Magazine magazine { private set; get; }

    public void Attach<T>(T component) //validate if can be attatched
    {
        if (component is Magazine)
        {
            if (magazine == null)
                Apply(component);
            else
            {
                Drop(component);
                Apply(component);
            }
        }
    }
    private void Apply<T>(T component) // apply the component to the gun
    {
        if (component is Magazine)
        {
            magazine = (Magazine)component; //ERROR: Cannot convert type `T' to `Magazine'
        }
    }

  ...// extra non relevant stuff 
}
```

My Magazine type is a class not a struct if that matters:

```
public class Magazine : Weapon_Component {//code }
```

So how do i correct for this error so it will be functional for any weapon component type?

Comment: What is the difference between `Attach` and `Apply`? Why can't `Attach` handle setting the `magazine` property? Will you have other `Weapon_Component` properties you are setting? If so, are you really expecting to type-check everything? Is this Unity3d? Or something else? There are new C# features that might help here, but you won't be able to use them if you're not using the latest C# language version. Your question needs a lot more context. See [ask] for advice on how to present your question in a clear, answerable way.

Comment: Well the difference in terms of their behaviour is one validates if you can attatch then if you can - then you apply it. I don't think that makes much difference in terms of why i get the error here. I am using unity i thought i had added the tag - i'll edit it in. I don't see how its a broad question lol.

Comment: First: questions in commented are intended to elicit new information _in the question_. You should be using the questions as a guide for how to improve the question; don't put your answers in comments as well. Second, you seem to be going about this wrongly. Checking a generic type parameter's type is antithetical to the proper use of generics, and is a strong hint that you're doing something wrong.

Comment: Personally, I would work toward a design that keeps components in a collection, not individual properties. Then generics might make more sense. If you are going to have components go in specific properties, you might as well have specific methods for each property as well. A third alternative would use polymorphism in the `Weapon_Component` type, such that each component knows what requirements exist and what property they are attached to. Bottom line, your question is just too broad. There are lots of possible answers, and none obviously better than any other.

Comment: Well say i had: `Attatch_Magazine()`then `Attatch_Grip()`, `Attatch_Paint()`, `Attatch_Silencer()` the list goes on.. it becomes really repetitive code for a lot of it so i thought generics would streamline it to simple `Attatch` and `Apply`

Comment: _"it becomes really repetitive code for a lot of it"_ -- yes, it does. But since you are checking each type individually in your method, you aren't going to get rid of the repetition. You're just going to hide it in that one method. You haven't streamlined anything with this approach.

Comment: Thats true, i was thinking it in terms of from a developers standpoint its easier for them to just use Attach(myObj) since my job is to make it as simple as possible for best productivity among the team. But if its not a good idea i'll stick to individual methods instead.

Comment: _"its not a good idea i'll stick to individual methods instead"_ -- as I mentioned, you _can_ have a simpler API (i.e. single method) without complicating things internally either. It's just that what you're trying to do at the moment isn't it. The problem here is that so far, all you've described is a syntactical issue with a variable assignment. You haven't shared anything about the broader problem, so it's not possible to address that broader problem (i.e. explain how to keep the public API simple without resorting to a large sequence of type-checks).

Comment: The problem in the question doesn't seem to be well defined. Are you looking for a better architecture or are you looking for a way to remove the error you're having?

Comment: Well i was initially looking to fix the error until you guys mentioned it was also bad design now i am doubting the whole thing. This is the full code: https://hastebin.com/tocumotohu.cs i cut a bit out to make the question shorter.

Comment: @Sir That's why I wanted to discuss this with you in a [chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/146971/discussion-between-deadzone-and-sir). If you're free to talk now, please join me there.

Comment: I'm not home at the moment but i am in an hour if you are still around?

Comment: Try joining the chat after an hour I will be there if I'm still awake.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is difficult to understand what design would work best in your scenario. You seem to be asking about a specific syntactical problem. There's not much detail in your question about the broader issues. However, making some inferences, here are a couple of options you might prefer to what you're doing now…

**1. Use a dictionary to track components**

```
public class Gun : Weapon
{
    private readonly Dictionary<Type, Weapon_Component> _components
        = new Dictionary<Type, Weapon_Component>();

    public void Attach(Weapon_Component component) //validate if can be attatched
    {
        if (_components.ContainsKey(component.GetType()))
        {
            Drop(component);
        }

        Apply(component);
    }

    private void Apply(Weapon_Component component) // apply the component to the gun
    {
        _components.Add(component.GetType(), component);
    }

    private void Drop(Weapon_Component component)
    {
        _components.RemoveKey(component.GetType());
    }
}
```

Note that the `Attach()`, `Apply()`, and `Drop()` methods could all be consolidated into a single assignment:

```
public void Attach(Weapon_Component component)
{
    _components[component.GetType()] = component;
}
```

Though, you might want to keep the `Drop()` method, for the scenario where you want to remove the component without replacing it. It's not clear from your question whether that ever happens.

**2. Design by interface and let components interact directly with weapons**

```
interface IWeapon { }

interface IGun : IWeapon
{
    Magazine Magazine { get; set; }
}

interface IWeaponComponent
{
    Attach(IWeapon weapon);
}

public class Gun : Weapon, IGun
{
    public Magazine Magazine { get; set; }
}

public class Magazine : IWeaponComponent
{
    public Attach(IWeapon weapon)
    {
        IGun gun = weapon as IGun;

        if (gun == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentException("Cannot attach a magazine to weapon that is not a gun");
        }

        gun.Magazine = this;
    }
}
```

Each of the above has its pros and cons, and of course these are not by any means your only options. I'm just trying to give you some ideas of what you might do, as well as help you understand, if these are not helpful to you, how you might narrow your question so that it's more answerable.

Comment: I've always learnt an interface is a "can do" type of setup so that is a bit confusing to see Magazine in `IGun` the magazine being in an interface is new to me. Curious about the pros of a dictionary here as opposed to individual properties for each type? Both are O(1) either way right?

Your first example highlights something that i just realised - i don't need to use generics since all my components for the gun have the same base class `Weapon_Component` so i can cast them. So now i realise my over thinking there thank you :)

Comment: @Sir: interfaces are just as much an "is a" relationship as inheritance is, but yes...in a sense they also represent "can do" and "has a" (methods and properties respectively...of course, this is true for classes and structs as well). Dictionary is O(1), yes...though of course hidden in that expression is the occasional O(n) reallocation of the backing hash table. But both dictionary or interfaces will have similar performance.

Answer (score 0):

If you're components must always be of type `Magazine` and solely that type, than there is absolutely no use of generics here.

If you want any type that **is** or inherits the type `Magazine` than yes generics can help, by constraining the generic parameter to inherit the said type like this:

```
where T : Magazine
```

But you can still make the type not generic but simply `Magazine`this should still do the job.

Or to fix your specific case you can do:

```
var magazine1 = component as Magazine;
if (magazine1 != null)
{
    magazine = magazine1;
}
```

But in your example it makes more sense to use one of the former 2 options, rather than the solution you already have.

Comment: There are other types - but ive only got as far as implementing the magazine for time being. I mention in the question there are varying types of components to attach :) An example would be a grip / silencer etc.

Comment: `public Magazine magazine { private set; get; }
` must be sometime that inherits or is of type `Magazine` to work, for that it makes more sense to have most base class/interface of all as your parameter type, instead of using generics. I will add some more info in the answer.

Comment: Yeah and my apply method won't apply it to that if the type is not a magazine as the if statement shows....

Comment: @Sir Well in that case it's just no brainer to go with a strong type as your argument type, namely `Magazine`. `private void Apply(Magazine component)`

Comment: What's the point of accepting any other type if you're only interested in `Magazine`?

Comment: A strong type is pointless what if i want to apply a grip or a silencer? They ain't the same type - i am not sure you read my question =/ I literally just told you i will be implementing other component types i just only got around to implemting the magazine type.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/146971/discussion-between-deadzone-and-sir).